# Button field(using image as button) focus issue

Tags: java-me, lwuit, setfocus, lwuit-button

In a single row we are displaying text field to enter the search text along with search image as button field. Below of that row we are displaying list of names.

The issue here is, the image button field not getting the focus during downward movement of keyboard arrow keys. But during upward movement its getting focus when we click the left arrow. But for downward movement is not getting focus for the up arrow movement.

Text field to enter the search text:

```
final TextField tfTeamSearch = new TextField();      
tfTeamSearch.setFocus(true);
```

Image button field:

```
btnSearchImage = new Button();
btnSearchImage.setIcon(imgSearchUnFocus);
btnSearchImage.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
btnSearchImage.getStyle().setBorder(null);
btnSearchImage.getStyle().setFont(font);
btnSearchImage.getSelectedStyle().setFont(font);
btnSearchImage.getPressedStyle().setFont(font);
btnSearchImage.getUnselectedStyle().setFont(font);
btnSearchImage.setFocusable(true);
```

Could u please help me how to set focus for both the upward and downward movement using arrow keys?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: you should use `tfTeamSearch.requestFocus()` instead of `tfTeamSearch.setFocus(true)` if you desire to set focus to `TextField`. `tfTeamSearch.setFocus(true)` changes only the style.

Secondly: you can use `Component` methods `setNextFocusDown`, `setNextFocusUp`, `setNextFocusLeft` or `setNextFocusRight` for setting next component under the focus.